# How to create a LWC multi select combobox?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

Is it possible to configure the [lightning-combobox](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/example) to allow multiple selections? I tried this method:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class ComboboxBasic extends LightningElement {

    @track value = '';
    selectedVals = [];

    get options() {
        return [
            { label: 'New', value: 'new' },
            { label: 'In Progress', value: 'inProgress' },
            { label: 'Finished', value: 'finished' },
        ];
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.selectedVals.push(event.detail.value);
        this.value = this.selectedVals.join(', ');
    }
}
```

but this doesn't keep mark the selected values in the drop down with the check mark. Is there a better method to implement some sort of `Drop down, checkbox, selector`?

Comment: Can't you instead use [`lightning-dual-listbox`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-dual-listbox/example)?

Comment: No, unfortunately. That would end up being a weird UI. I'm trying to implement this for a user to filter the results that are displayed on the page. So, like if my page displays a set of Students. If nothing is selected in the list, it displays all, or the user can use the list to select Students who are in 9th grade and 10th grade. The listbox feels more like a setting than a filter when using in a web component.

Comment: might just have to use some default JS to get this implemented

Comment: I have since defaulted to using the lighting-checkbox-group. It looks nice and serves the purpose of allowing people to select multiple values. You may just need to do some rejiggering to get the values to populate properly in multi select picklist fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, you are limited to what is in the [LWC spec](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/specification).

However, the roadmap for combobox is unknown. [There are no planned upgrades to it](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_components_roadmap.htm&type=5) 
(unlike `datatable`)

And then, the [design spec here](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/combobox/#Open-and-Selecting) does have the CSS and raw markup for multiple selection (you need to implement your own component borrowing from the styles).

FYI, I ended up having to create my own component out of borrowing from the official blueprints, and it's just something you have to do if you can't wait for the base combobox component to have more features.

Answer (score 8):

You can have a look at this Git Repo : [MultiPickList using lwc](https://github.com/sudikrt/lwc/tree/master/multiPickListDemo)

Configuration Option

```
@api label  = ''; //Name of the dropDown
@api maxselected  = 2; //Max selected item display
@api options; // List of items to display
@api showfilterinput = false; //show filterbutton
@api showrefreshbutton = false; //show the refresh button
@api showclearbutton = false; //show the clear button

 <c-multi-pick-list label="Pick-List" options={msOptions}  showclearbutton='true' showfilterinput='true' showrefreshbutton='true' onitemselected={handleOnItemSelected}></c-multi-pick-list>
```

This will fire `onitemselected` event which will provide you array of selected items

optionally can call `getSelectedItems ()` of  `c-multi-pick-list` component which will also return the array of selected items

[Live Demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/ijxZKFc5uGVblesakinS)

Comment: this is great sample of custom multi-picklist, it provide the search value and support multiple selection

Answer (score 4):

There is a standard component present in salesforce component library to build this functionality. Find the link below:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-dual-listbox/example

Comment: The person is asking about a multi-select combobox, not a dual listbox. That is not the same component at all.

Comment: @EtienneRocheleau, what you're saying is true, but the dual listbox fits very well to the given use case. [Salesforce says](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/documentation): "To support multiple selection, use lightning-dual-listbox instead." I believe many will find Gaurav's answer useful in this context.

Answer (score 3):

Functionally, it would work as checkbox group:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-checkbox-group/example

Unless you're tied to the combobox ui.

Comment: This. If you only have a few options, checkbox is better UX.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late, but I have built a combobox that allows multiple selections and displays them as pills. It's very reliable and I've used it in multiple projects.

The code is on [github](https://github.com/rapsacnz/MultiSelect)

Usage:

```
<c-multi-select name="jobStatus" label="Job Status" multi-select-by-default="true"
  value={jobStatus} variant="label-inline" options={jobStatusOptions} dropdown-length="10"
  onchange={handleJobStatusOptionsChange} >
</c-multi-select>
```

Set options dynamically using this format:

```
this.jobStatusOptions = [
  { label: 'Value 1', value: 'Value 1' },
  { label: 'Value 2', value: 'Value 2' },
  { label: 'Value 3', value: 'Value 3' },
];
```

To handle a change:

```
handleJobStatusOptionsChange(event) {
  let value = event.detail.value;
  //do something with the value
}
```

Looks like:
[image: multiselect in action]

Comment: It seems that the LWC component doesn't work. It didn't compile and required some modifications to make it work. Thanks for sharing it anyway, I hope I'll find some time to create a PR with the changes I did.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2022**

I wrote a whole article on how to create a LWC multi select combobox that covers all functions of the standard [lightning-combobox](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/example) and additionally supports multi select:

[How to create the LWC Multi Select Combobox that Salesforce is still missing](https://medium.com/@svierk/how-to-create-the-lwc-multi-select-combobox-that-salesforce-is-still-missing-c7bf3a2850dd)

The source code including JEST unit tests and JSDoc comments is available here:

[Custom Multi Select Combobox](https://github.com/svierk/awesome-lwc-collection/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/multiSelectCombobox)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be this component now that can probably help with whatever you were trying to do: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-pill-container/documentation

However as mentioned without custom code, I do not believe it will be easy to combine this + a combobox without re-coding both components.